# Python calculation/get function with menubutton

Tags: python, python-2.7, drop-down-menu, widget, tkinter

I am having problems when trying to set up a calculation for an NFL Simulator. User selects a team from a menu and each team has three variables: power rank, win percentage and luck. When making the calculation, after user selects the teams and simulates, how do I pull the variables that go along with that team and put them into the calculation? I am also getting a 'AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'power_rankings'' error currently.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

teams = ['Arizona Cardinals','Atlanta Falcons','Baltimore Ravens', 
'Buffalo Bills','Carolina Panthers','Chicago Bears','Cincinnati Bengals',
'Cleveland Browns','Dallas Cowboys','Denver Broncos','Detroit Lions',
'Green Bay Packers','Houston Texans','Indianapolis Colts','Jacksonville Jaguars',
'Kansas City Chiefs','Miami Dolphins','Minnesota Vikings','New England Patriots',
'New Orleans Saints','New York Giants','New York Jets','Oakland Raiders',
'Philadelphia Eagles','Pittsburgh Steelers','San Diego Chargers','San Francisco 49ers',
'Seattle Seahawks','St. Louis Rams','Tampa Bay Buccaneers','Tennessee Titans',
'Washington Redskins']

power_rankings = [10, 28, 18, 23, 6, 13, 7, 25, 8, 1, 9, 26, 31, 11, 32, 12, 21,
29, 3, 4, 17, 24, 30, 14, 15, 16, 5, 2, 20, 22, 19, 27]

winning_percentage = [.583, .250, .500, .333, .750, .500, .667, .333, .583, .833,
.583, .458, .167, .667, .250, .750, .500, .292, .750, .818, .417, .417, .333, .583,
.417, .417, .667, .909, .417, .250, .417, .250]

luck = random.randrange(0,50)

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.grid()

        self.headerFont = ("Helvetica", "16", "bold italic")

        global root
        root = master
        root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (300, 180, 200, 150))
        root.title("NFL Sim")

        global var1
        global var2
        var1 = tk.StringVar(root)
        var1.set('Arizona Cardinals')
        var2 = tk.StringVar(root)
        var2.set('Arizona Cardinals')

        self.addTeams()
        self.addOutput()

    def addTeams(self):
        self.lblTitle = Label(self.frame, text = "NFL Simulator",
                              font = self.headerFont).grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)

        self.lblTeamA = Label(self.frame,text = "Away Team")
        self.lblTeamA.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "ew")
        self.txtTeamA = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, var1, *teams)
        self.txtTeamA.pack(side='right', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.txtTeamA.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.lblTeamB = Label(self.frame,text = "Home Team")
        self.lblTeamB.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "ew")
        self.txtTeamB = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, var2, *teams)
        self.txtTeamB.pack(side='right', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.txtTeamB.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    def addOutput(self):
        self.btnCalc = Button(self.frame,text = "Simulate Game",command = self.calc)
        self.btnCalc.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

        self.lblScoreAPrompt = Label(self.frame,text = "Away Team Score")
        self.lblScoreAPrompt.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = "ew")
        self.lblScoreA = Label(self.frame, bg = "white", anchor = "w")
        self.lblScoreA.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = "ew")

        self.lblScoreBPrompt = Label(self.frame,text = "Home Team Score")
        self.lblScoreBPrompt.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = "ew")
        self.lblScoreB = Label(self.frame, bg = "white", anchor = "w")
        self.lblScoreB.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = "ew")

    def getTeamA(self):
        return self.getTeamA

    def getTeamB(self):
        return self.getTeamB

    def calc(self):
        PowerRank = int(self.power_rankings.get())
        WinPerc = int(self.winning_percentage.get()) * 100
        Luck = int(self.luck.get())
        HomeBonus = 10

        TeamAScore = (PowerRank + WinPerc + Luck) / 3
        TeamBScore = (PowerRank + WinPerc + Luck + HomeBonus) / 3

        self.lblScoreA["text"] = TeamAScore
        self.lblScoreB["text"] = TeamBScore


 def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def calc(self):
    global var1, var2

    selected_index = teams.index(var1.get())

    PowerRank = power_rankings[ selected_index ]
    WinPerc = winning_percentage[ selected_index ] * 100
    Luck = random.randrange(0,50)
    HomeBonus = 10

    # ...
```

It get selected name for Away Team, use it to find index in `teams`, and the index is use to get value from `power_rankings` and `winning_percentage`. For Home Team use `var2`.

---

**BTW:** In place of `global var1, var2` you could use `self.var1`, `self.var2`. But you have to use `self.var1`, `self.var2` everywhere in code.

Comment: Thanks, working well now. Also changed up the self.var1 and self.var2 and took out the global.